# Flex DataGrid Vertical Lines render on top of Vbox

Tags: apache-flex, datagrid

I am currently working in Flex 3.5

Inside a DataGrid with fixed columns, there is a button that causes a VBox to appear on top of part of the DataGrid. However the vertical lines that divide the columns shows up on top of the VBox.

I was looking for an attribute that would fix this in the Flex API but didn't discern any of them to be appropriate. I'm open to any possible answers.

Comment: Could you post your code?

Comment: The grid is most likely doing some programatic drawing to make those lines. How are you placing the VBox on top of the grid? Do you add it as child to the grid, or are both the grid and the VBox siblings inside of a parent component. If you show us your code, and the answer might become apparent.

Comment: Unfortunately my company policy doesnt allow me to post code online, but the VBox is being called as an item of a DataGridColumn.

Comment: So on the display list, if the `VBox` is a child of a `DataGridColumn`, then it is very likely that the grid is drawing on a "layer" that is above your box. You have to find a way to add it to the display list so that it's on top of the data grid component (not a child of it).